# MySQL ODBC 32 vs 64 bit

Tags: mysql, 64-bit, odbc, 32-bit, win64

I have a 32-bit application that must run on a Windows x64 server using a 64-bit version of MySQL.
Should I use a 32-bit ODBC driver or a 64-bit ODBC driver?
Or should I install a 32-bit version of MySQL too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to

1. install ODBC 32-bit on Windows 64-bit
2. have my application (32-bit) running
   fine with 32-bit ODBC "against" 64-bit
   MySQL on 64-bit Windows OS (2008 R2)

To achieve 1) I had to modify install.bat provided with the zip package of MySQL ODBC to take into account the fact that the 32-bit driver must be installed in `c:\windows\syswow64`.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM #########################################################
REM
REM \brief  Install myodbc.
REM
REM         This exists for those working with the Windows source
REM         distribution.
REM
REM \sa     README.win
REM
REM #########################################################

SET installdir=none
IF EXIST %windir%\system\nul   SET installdir=%windir%\system
IF EXIST %windir%\system32\nul SET installdir=%windir%\system32

REM ****************************
REM * check syswow64 folder too ...
REM ****************************
IF EXIST %windir%\syswow64\nul SET installdir=%windir%\syswow64

IF %installdir%==none GOTO :doError5


IF "%1"=="1" GOTO :doDebug
IF "%1"=="0" GOTO :doNormal
GOTO doSyntax

:doNormal

REM ****************************
REM * syswow64 must be specified
REM ****************************
IF EXIST %installdir%\myodbc3i.exe GOTO :doError4

REM ****
REM * Find out the bin/lib directory, or use default
REM ****
SET libdir=lib
SET bindir=bin
IF EXIST lib\release\myodbc3.lib         SET libdir=lib\release
IF EXIST lib\relwithdebinfo\myodbc3.lib  SET libdir=lib\relwithdebinfo
IF EXIST bin\release\myodbc3i.exe        SET bindir=bin\release
IF EXIST bin\relwithdebinfo\myodbc3i.exe SET bindir=bin\relwithdebinfo

REM ****
REM * Copying myodbc libraries and executables to install dir...
REM ****
IF NOT EXIST %bindir%\myodbc3c.exe GOTO :doError2
IF NOT EXIST %libdir%\myodbc3.lib  GOTO :doError2
IF NOT EXIST %libdir%\myodbc3S.lib GOTO :doError2
IF NOT EXIST %bindir%\myodbc3i.exe GOTO :doError2
IF NOT EXIST %bindir%\myodbc3m.exe GOTO :doError2
copy %libdir%\myodbc3S.dll %installdir%
copy %libdir%\myodbc3S.lib %installdir%
copy %libdir%\myodbc3.dll  %installdir%
copy %libdir%\myodbc3.lib  %installdir%
copy %bindir%\myodbc3i.exe      %installdir%
copy %bindir%\myodbc3m.exe      %installdir%
copy %bindir%\myodbc3c.exe      %installdir%
copy doc\*.hlp             %installdir%

REM ****
REM * Registering driver...
REM *
REM * We can do this with myodbc3i.exe or the MS Windows ODBCConf.exe. It
REM * may be safer to use the ODBCConf.exe when we think about such things
REM * as 64bit windows.
REM ****

REM ****************************
REM * syswow64 must be specified
REM ****************************
%installdir%\myodbc3i -a -d -t"MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver;DRIVER=%installdir%\myodbc3.dll;SETUP=%installdir%\myodbc3S.dll"

GOTO doSuccess

:doDebug
REM ****
REM * Find out the bin/lib directory, or use default
REM ****
SET libdir=lib
IF EXIST lib\debug\myodbc3d.lib          SET libdir=lib\debug

IF NOT EXIST %libdir%\myodbc3d.lib goto doError3
IF NOT EXIST %libdir%\myodbc3E.lib goto doError3
IF NOT EXIST %installdir%\myodbc3i.exe goto doError1
REM ****
REM * Copying myodbc debug libraries to install dir...
REM ****
copy %libdir%\myodbc3E.dll %installdir%
copy %libdir%\myodbc3E.lib %installdir%
copy %libdir%\myodbc3d.dll %installdir%
copy %libdir%\myodbc3d.lib %installdir%

REM ****
REM * Registering driver...
REM ****

REM ****************************
REM * syswow64 must be specified
REM ****************************
%installdir%\myodbc3i -a -d -t"MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver (debug);DRIVER=myodbc3d.dll;SETUP=myodbc3E.dll"

goto doSuccess


:doSuccess
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "| DONE                                                |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| Hopefully things went well; the Connector/ODBC      |"
ECHO "| files have been copied to the system directory      |"
ECHO "| and the driver has been registered.                 |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| Connector/ODBC is ready to use.                     |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| The most common thing to do next is to go to the    |"
ECHO "| Control Panel and find the ODBC Administrator -     |"
ECHO "| then use it to create a Data Source Name (DSN)      |"
ECHO "| so you (and your application) can connect to a      |"
ECHO "| MySQL server.                                       |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
EXIT /B 0

:doError1
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "| ERROR                                               |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| The non-debug version of Connector/ODBC needs to be |"
ECHO "| installed.                                          |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
PAUSE
EXIT /B 1

:doError2
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "| ERROR                                               |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| Connector/ODBC not built. Consider executing        |"
ECHO "| Build.bat.                                          |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
PAUSE
EXIT /B 1

:doError3
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "| ERROR                                               |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| Connector/ODBC (debug) not built. Consider executing|"
ECHO "| Build.bat.                                          |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
PAUSE
EXIT /B 1

:doError4
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "| ERROR                                               |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| Existing Connector/ODBC installed. Request ignored. |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
PAUSE
EXIT /B 1

:doError5
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "| ERROR                                               |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| Can't find the Windows system directory             |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
PAUSE
EXIT /B 1

:doSyntax
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "| Install.bat                                         |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| DESCRIPTION                                         |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| Use this to copy the driver and supporting files    |"
ECHO "| to the system directory and register the driver.    |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| You can not properly install the debug version      |"
ECHO "| without first installing the regular version.       |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| SYNTAX                                              |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| Install <debug>                                     |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "| <debug>  must be;                                   |"
ECHO "|              0 - to install a regular build         |"
ECHO "|              1 - to install a debug version         |"
ECHO "|                                                     |"
ECHO "+-----------------------------------------------------+"
```

Answer (score 6):

You would need to install a 32-bit SQL and ODBC driver seeing as how your application is in 32-bit. For compatibility reasons.

I am still searching, will edit.

** EDIT

To work around this problem, use the appropriate version of the ODBC Administrator tool. If you build and then run an application as a 32-bit application on a 64-bit operating system, you must create the ODBC data source by using the ODBC Administrator tool in %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. To indicate the type of DSN, you can add "_32" to the 32-bit user DSNs and "_64" to the 64-bit user DSNs.

From [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976).

** EDIT

If you want to have a workaround, you need to create you ODBC data source by using the Admin tool found in. 
This is also explained in the same link.

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

Comment: thank you Justin! 

I indeed was able to install 32bit odbc and have my application runnng fine. (as you wrote the odbc DSN is shown in %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) thanks stefano